# Merge several text files into one

Tags: c++, windows, text-files, command-prompt

I have a directory of several thousand text files. Each text file has a single line. To merge them I used `copy * aggregate.txt` in the command prompt in Windows but the lines have been copied without any spacing between them.

So how do I combine the files such that lines are separated? Insert a newline character each time a file is copied?

If there's a way to do in command-prompt or using windows batch program or I could do it by writing a c++ program if you could tell me how to read all files in a directory one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may take a while to start as thousands of files are involved
Change the `d:\folder` and place the batch file somewhere else that is not in d:\folder

```
@echo off    
pushd "d:\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ') do (
type "%%a" >>aggregate.txt
echo.>>aggregate.txt
)
popd
```

Or this which should start straight away:

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\folder"
dir /b /a-d >"c:\file.tmp"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\file.tmp) do (
type "%%a" >>aggregate.txt
echo.>>aggregate.txt
)
del "c:\file.tmp"
popd
```

Comment: The second one did not work while the first one did. Now the no. of lines in aggregate is 3 more than the number of files.

Comment: Delete the aggregate.txt file before running it.  The second one requires write permission to c:\

Comment: yes there was no aggregate before running it. What about the 3 extra lines?

Comment: Lol the 3 extra lines were from the batch file.

Comment: @Arjun U Good catch.  I modified the batch to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR %%i IN (*) DO if /i not "%%i"=="aggregate.txt" TYPE "%%i"&ECHO(
)>aggregate.txt
```

Personally, I'd use this...

Comment: That worked but there are more lines in aggregate than the number of files. I can't figure out why.

Comment: You can simplify it further by removing the setlocal. :)  But it will also parse aggregate.txt as it goes won't it?

Comment: Yes - possibly the source of the "extra lines" is including `aggregate.txt` in the aggregation. I'd deleted it before running the tests. The amended batch should now exclude the report file.